# Action Controller Exception: Using GET instead of DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following for my routes.rb file:

```
Hchq::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
end
```

When I run `rake routes` I get:

```
      users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
   sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
    session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   sessions#destroy
     signup        /signup(.:format)         users#new
     signin        /signin(.:format)         sessions#new
    signout DELETE /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
```

and yet, when I go to `http://localhost:3000/signout` I get the following:

[image: routing error: Action Controller Exception]

In the log I get: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/signout"):`

Which, shouldn't I be having a [DELETE] instead of a [GET] on the /signout route? If so how do I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By navigating straight from your browser to that address, you're actually performing a GET request. Browsers by default are submitting GET requests when a user enters a URL and ask it to render the page.

You should insert a link in your view using `#link_to` and passing the `DELETE` method as an option, like this:

```
link_to "Signout", signout_path, :method => :delete
```

Comment: Yup.  If you read the background (check guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) most browsers don't support anything other than GET, and POST, so Rails fakes this with a hidden input named "method".

Comment: Awesome! I should have thought of that.